# Некорректно отображается Table View Section

Tags: xcode

[image: Секция в xcode]
При выделении секции ее "затемнение" немного ниже чем должно быть. Это проявлется только при наличии навигации сверху (без навигации выделяется нормально).
Ячейки которые не входят в синюю область не кликаются в редакторе и туда не переносятся объекты.

У ячеек выставлен кастомный статичный вид.

В чем проблема и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю это не влияет на программу, только отображение в XCODE. Но решить это можно выбрав в Top Bar - **opaque navigation bar**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Yes, this is only xcode problem, but not inconvenient